# Using global inside a closure in PHP

Tags: php, variables, closures, global

Somehow, the following results in NULL. Why is this the case? I find it important to know, because the `use` statements does not support variable variables.

```
function a() {
    $a = "a";
    $aa = function() {
        global $a;
        var_dump($a);
    };
    $aa();
}
a();
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is `NULL` because there is no global with name `$a`.

The following would print "global":

```
$a = "global"; // global variable initialization

function a() {
    $a = "a";
    $aa = function() {
        global $a;
        var_dump($a);
    };
    $aa();
}
a();
```

Comment: Read the question please. Although your assumption is correct I have to refer to a variable variable.

Comment: @user2180613: You asked "Why is this the case?", and he answered "because there is no global with name $a". What else do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this :

```
function a() {
    $a = "a";
    function b() {
        global $a;
        var_dump($a);
    };
    $aa = "b";
    $aa();
}
a();
```

Comment: Not applicable. The use case requires a closure, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a reference to the variable variables.

```
function a() {

    $a = "b";
    $b = "variable";

    $ref = &$$a;

    $aa = function() use ($ref) {
        var_dump($ref);
    };
    $aa();
}
a();
```

which outputs: `string(8) "variable"`

Answer (score 0):

Variable `$t` is the variable variable you can access with `$$a`. Note that inside the function `a()`, `$t` is never used, so should be what you want.

```
$t = 3;
$a = 't';
function a()
{
    global $a, $$a;
    $x = $$a;
    $b = function()  use ($x) {
        echo $x;
    };
    $b();
}
a();
```

The code prints `3`.

Comment: The scope of `a` is not meant to be left. `global` was not a correct choice on my behalf.

Comment: well, in that case you should explain what you want better.

Answer (score 0):

`global $a` access a *global variable* called `$a`. It is not the *local variable* in the function `a`. Since you have never initialized a global variable called `$a`, it is NULL.

In order for local variables to be usable inside an anonymous function, they must be captured using a `use` clause. Local variables can either be captured by value or by reference.

If you want to capture by value (which means the value of the local variable `$a` is copied into the closure at the time it's defined):

```
function a() {
    $a = "a";
    $aa = function() use ($a) {
        var_dump($a);
    };
    $aa();
}
a();
```

If you want to capture by reference (which means inside the closure it directly references the variable `$a`):

```
function a() {
    $a = "a";
    $aa = function() use (&$a) {
        var_dump($a);
    };
    $aa();
}
a();
```

In this case both would be the same. But if you modified the variable after the closure was created, and before it is run, it would give a different result (the capture by value would still have the previous value).